# remove inline style on a svg image

Tags: css, svg

I have a svg img (home icon in navbar) and reduced its code to this:

```css
body {
background-color: #ccc;
}

.navtsvg {
  float: left;
  fill: white;
  height: 17 px;
  width: 19 px;
}

.fil0 {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <a href='index.php'>
    <svg class='navtsvg' viewBox="0 0 4.47 3.81" <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
         <![CDATA[
          .fil0 {fill:white}
         ]]>
        </style>
       </defs>
         <polygon class="fil0" points="2.23,0 4.47,2 4.14,2.3 2.23,0.59 0.33,2.3 0,2 "/>
         <path class="fil0" d="M3.62 2.25l-1.28 -1.14c-0.06,-0.05 -0.16,-0.05 -0.22,0l-1.27 1.14c-0.06,0.05 -0.11,0.16 -0.11,0.24l0 1.19c0,0.07 0.07,0.13 0.16,0.13l0.85 0 0 -0.76c0,-0.08 0.07,-0.14 0.15,-0.14l0.67 0c0.09,0 0.16,0.06 0.16,0.14l0 0.76 0.85 0c0.08,0 0.15,-0.06 0.15,-0.13l0 -1.19c0,-0.08 -0.05,-0.18 -0.11,-0.24z"/>
      </svg>
  </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

But removing inline style the image dissapear, as it doesn't exist on display.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will work, try this code

```css
body{background:#ccc;}
.navtsvg{
     float:left;
     height:17px;
     width:19px;
 }

 .fil0{
     fill:white;
 }
```

```html
<svg class='navtsvg' viewBox="0 0 4.47 3.81">
   <polygon class="fil0" points="2.23,0 4.47,2 4.14,2.3 2.23,0.59 0.33,2.3 0,2 "/>
   <path class="fil0" d="M3.62 2.25l-1.28 -1.14c-0.06,-0.05 -0.16,-0.05 -0.22,0l-1.27 1.14c-0.06,0.05 -0.11,0.16 -0.11,0.24l0 1.19c0,0.07 0.07,0.13 0.16,0.13l0.85 0 0 -0.76c0,-0.08 0.07,-0.14 0.15,-0.14l0.67 0c0.09,0 0.16,0.06 0.16,0.14l0 0.76 0.85 0c0.08,0 0.15,-0.06 0.15,-0.13l0 -1.19c0,-0.08 -0.05,-0.18 -0.11,-0.24z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: and is it possible to remove inline `viewBox`  too?

Comment: @blueSky not possible, viewbox is not a style

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="navtsvgContainer" href='index.php'>
    <svg class='navtsvg' viewBox="0 0 4.47 3.81"
        <polygon points="2.23,0 4.47,2 4.14,2.3 2.23,0.59 0.33,2.3 0,2 "/>
        <path d="M3.62 2.25l-1.28 -1.14c-0.06,-0.05 -0.16,-0.05 -0.22,0l-1.27 1.14c-0.06,0.05 -0.11,0.16 -0.11,0.24l0 1.19c0,0.07 0.07,0.13 0.16,0.13l0.85 0 0 -0.76c0,-0.08 0.07,-0.14 0.15,-0.14l0.67 0c0.09,0 0.16,0.06 0.16,0.14l0 0.76 0.85 0c0.08,0 0.15,-0.06 0.15,-0.13l0 -1.19c0,-0.08 -0.05,-0.18 -0.11,-0.24z"/>
    </svg>
</a>
<style>
    .navtsvg{
        fill:#ffffff;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:block;
    }
    .navtsvgContainer{
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>
```